# mySQL select every record that does not exist in another table

Tags: mysql, sql, join, select, subquery

I have 3 tables:

- users (id_user)
- achievements (id_achievement)
- user_achievements (id_user, id_achievement)

I need help selecting every achievement that a user has not yet completed.

Comment: With that data structure, how do you know what the achievment is?

Comment: it has more fields but every user and every achievement has a id

Comment: For all users or a specific user only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider a `cross join` that generates all combinations of users and achievements, and a `not exists` condition with a correlated subquery to filter out those that were completed already:

```
select u.id_user, a.id_achievement
from users u
cross join achievements a
where not exists (
    select 1 
    from user_achievements ua 
    where ua.id_user = u.id_user and ua.id_achievement = a.id_achievement
)
```

Comment: It worked, thanks alot, had no idea it existed cross join, well, guess I gotta read a bit more